# Why can't form_tag and form_for be used in helper functions [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, frontend

I'm doing a rails project and I'm refractoring some code. Because I use the same type of collection_select with a form_tag, I decided to create a helper for it where I just change the path & request.

However, I noticed that when I use form_for in a helper function, it only returns the last line. In the following example, it will only return the submit button and if I remove the submit button, it will only return the select.

```
def form_select #### Helper Function
     form_tag po_path(@pos), method: "get" do 
         collection_select :po, :category, @pos.categories.order(:id), :id, :name, selected: (@items.empty? ? "" : @items.first.category.id)
         submit_tag "Show items" 
     end 
  end 
end
```

My question is; why does this not work, but the following does?

```
<!-- In the view -->
<%= form_tag po_path(@pos), method: "get" do %> 
        <%= collection_select :po, :category, @pos.categories.order(:id), :id, :name, selected: (@items.empty? ? "" : @items.first.category.id)%> 
        <%= submit_tag "Show items" %> 
    <% end %>
```

It does the same for form_for.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Because it returns the last statement executed by method, also for code reusability you can create partials

Comment: Since form_for/tag are blocks, I thought it would return an object that was interpreted by ruby as an html form. Wouldn't that vlbe returned by the helper funxtion? If it returns only the last line, why does it show everything in the view?

Comment: `form_for/tag` are not blocks - they are methods defined by the Rails helpers. You pass blocks to the helper to which they yield between the `<form>` and `</form>`. These blocks will return the result of the last expression just like everything else in ruby.

Comment: Ah, I see; I got the concept mixed up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When calling the form helpers (or any other html helpers) in a helper method you need to call `concat` (or manually concatenate the strings).

```
def form_select #### Helper Function
  form_tag po_path(@pos), method: "get" do 
    concat collection_select :po, :category, @pos.categories.order(:id), :id, :name, selected: (@items.empty? ? "" : @items.first.category.id)
    concat submit_tag "Show items" 
  end 
end
```

This is because the helper does not return a concatenated html string as you are expecting. Rather the blocks returns the result of the last expression just like any other Ruby block.

```
def foo(&block) 
  yield
end

# returns "baz"
foo do
  "bar"
  "baz"
end
```

It works in ERB since the `<%= %>` [are *expressions*](http://www.stuartellis.name/articles/erb/#writing-templates) where the renderer should substitute the code element with the result of the code (as a string) when it renders the template. This is somewhat like `puts` but it writes to the template buffer.

```
<%= foo do %>
  <%= "bar" %> <%= "baz" %>
<% end %>
```

This example will output "bar baz" to the template.

But you should really consider using a partial here instead.